# PHP Curl to get ajax data or something like that

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I don't know if the question is right, but here is my problem..

I want to crawl this site: https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/compete/leaderboards to get the leaderboard data.

When I do so with the following code, I only get the header + footer, but not the leaderboard data.

```
$client = new HttpClient();
$client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");
$client->setUri("https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/compete/leaderboards");
$content = $client->send()->getBody();
var_dump($content);
```

Is there a problem with my curl or can this data not be curled? If so, maybe you got a solution for me ;)

Comment: after scraping the first page, you will need to scrap the ajax url too, to get it's data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open the Developer Tools in your browser you can see which extra requests are done to get the leaderboard filled. You should use the url `https://www.easports.com/cgw/api/fifa/fut/leaderboard?platform=xboxone&region=ams&period=curr` to get the leaderboard. This returns a JSON in the following layout:

```
[
{
  "rank": 1,
  "persona": "persona",
  "hasProfile": false,
  "wins": 1,
  "skill": "6",
  "qualified": 0
}]
```

Using your code this would be:

```
$client = new HttpClient();
$client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");
$client->setUri("https://www.easports.com/cgw/api/fifa/fut/leaderboard?platform=xboxone&region=ams&period=curr");
$content = $client->send()->getBody();
var_dump($content);
```

Which can then be processed for example with:

```
$client = new HttpClient();
$client->setAdapter("Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl");
$client->setUri("https://www.easports.com/cgw/api/fifa/fut/leaderboard?platform=xboxone&region=ams&period=curr");
$content = $client->send()->getBody();
$leaderBoard = json_decode($content);
foreach($leaderBoard as $member){
    echo $member['rank'] . '. ' . $member['persona'] . '(' . $member['wins'] . ' Wins)<br />';
}
```

Comment: @HansMartin any idea how to get separate months through this api, and not just current and previous? thanks